# How to solve unregnised certificate from my Asha X201

Tags: java-me

I am developing a application in nokia asha but I got the http connection  error

`Certificate was issued by an unrecognized entity ssl error ver 49`.

I am developing app with nokia asha sdk

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the server is using a self signed certificate, you will have to change the certificate on the serve to match one of the trusted root CA's on the device.